# Storing and retrieving data from Firebase comes back in different format

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to build this timetracker app where users can log how many hours per day they have worked. To give you an idea of what my app looks like, I put together a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9vhfmjpy/

Here comes the tricky part. Whenever I try to store the data into a node in firebase by doing this:

```
submitHours() {
  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;      
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("userhours/" + uid)
    .set(this.rows)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
},
```

it is turned into an object with an index value, as such:

```
userhours: {
    userId: {
        0: {
            name: "username",
            times: "time here"
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/kpglr9

Having it formatted with that index makes it really to maintain. I can't effectively update/set/retrieve nodes.
I can use something like

```
        loadUserHours() {
        var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
        firebase.database().ref("userhours").once("value").then((data) => {
            const allRows = [];
            let obj = data.val();
            for (let key in obj) {
                allRows.push({
                    name: obj[key][0].name,
                    times: obj[key][0].times
                })
            }
            console.log(allRows)
            this.rows = allRows
        })
    },
```

to simply retrieve the values, but now... if there is more than 1 user in the `userhours` node I can't really update my node. If I try to use my `submitHours()` method now after updating the values for user #2 (https://prnt.sc/kpgqzq) it'll store the new information in a new node, in something that looks like this: https://prnt.sc/kpgqgs,

Can anyone help me out on how I can effectively store and retrieve data for my app?

Thanks a ton

Comment: "I can't effectively update/set/retrieve nodes. I can use something like" What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: In my second screenshot (https://prnt.sc/kpgqzq) , I'm logged in as user joe@gmail.com , if I add numbers to any input field in his row and hit Submit, it'll create a new node under uid "erik@gmail.com" as seen by here https://prnt.sc/kpgqgs . How can I make sure that Joe gets stored under the correct node? In my second screenshot you'll see that instead of creating a new node for joe@gmail.com, a new node with erik@gmail.com is created, storing both users in an array..I simply want to hit submit and only store the logged in user's value in a separate node

Comment: Does it make sense what I’m trying to achieve, Frank?

Comment: Honestly, I'm finding it very hard to follow, so was hoping somebody else would spot it. There's just too much going on. Is the problem that your data is written under the wrong UID?